# vaadin7 getting values from container

Tags: vaadin, jfreechart, vaadin7

Currently I load data from database to Table in vaadin7 by implementing LazyQueryContainer.
Here is my code:

```
 final LazyQueryContainer container = new LazyQueryContainer(factory, /* index */null, /* batchSize */50, false);               
        for (Column c : columns) {
            container.addContainerProperty(c.getCaption(), c.getType(), null, false, true);
        }
table.setContainerDataSource(container);
```

It works as expected.

However I want to display the data not in table format but as a chart. I have already implemented Jfreechart so all I need to do is somehow retrieve the data from the container (or maybe from the table?)

I can iterate over `container.getContainerPropertyIds()` but I am not sure whether it is the right thing to do.

How can I get the content of one column of the table? For example the first column in my table is called "date" and I would like to get all date values in a list, or array,etc.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: does the chart need the same data as the table and is the amount reasonable?  if you are going to read the container from start to end, you will more or less loading each row from the db.

Comment: yes, the chart need the same data.

Comment: As **cfrick** already said, this is not the intention of the lazy-container to provide all rows (doesn't matter for which column). If you really need this data you can iterate over the container items, but I'd prefer to use a seperate db-request for this usecase.

Comment: yeah, that's what I was afraid of:-)